# Placeholder text (design process only) in Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, placeholder

Is it possible to create placeholder text that is only visible during the layout design process in Android Studio?

For example, say I have 2 TextViews in a linear layout that are going to be dynamically populated. During the design phase, I use placeholder text to ensure I get padding and such correct. I often forget to remove placeholder text, so during loading of the new data, the old data will appear for a split second... looks tacky.

It would be cool if there was a field similar to `android:placeholderText="This is placeholder text"` that would only display in the preview. There isn't such a thing that I've happened to have missed is there?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Yes it is (these days), and I believe that this is probably what you're looking for:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes - specifically: `tools:text=""`

Comment: Awesome. I knew I had seen that somewhere! For others, remember to include the namespace `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your root element.

Comment: this will work for most `android:` attributes - the 2nd most useful to `text` might be: `tools:visibility="visible"` to show normally-hidden elements in design view (or vice-versa)

Comment: I also frequently use `tools:src` for `ImageView`s used for displaying user avatars or other dynamic content.